# Angular JS - how to change text inside the button based on the variable value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have the following button in the template:

```
<button ng-if="downloadInProgress != true"
                  ng-click="downloadData()"
                  class="button button-full button-outline button-positive welcomeButton">
              {{ 'DOWNLOAD_SOUNDS' | translate }}
          </button>
```

And i would like to change the text:

```
{{ 'DOWNLOAD_SOUNDS' | translate }}
```

to

```
{{ 'DOWNLOADING' | translate }} {{ downloadProgress}} {{ '%' | translate }}
```

If the value

```
downloadInProgress == true
```

Now i'm using two buttons in the template and show/hide one from them in order of the variable value:

```
<button ng-if="downloadInProgress != true"
                  ng-click="downloadData()"
                  class="button button-full button-outline button-positive welcomeButton">
              {{ 'DOWNLOAD_SOUNDS' | translate }}
          </button>

          <button ng-if="downloadInProgress == true && (downloadProgress >= 0 && downloadProgress < 100)"
                  class="button button-full button-outline button-positive welcomeButton">
              {{ 'DOWNLOADING' | translate }} {{ downloadProgress}} {{ '%' | translate }}
              <ion-spinner class="spinner-positive welcomePageDownloadProgressSpinner" icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>
          </button>
```

But i think that this approach is not good way, because if the value is changing i noticed that buttons are blinking if are changed.

Is it possible it to solve it with using only the one button?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ (!downloadInProgress ? 'DOWNLOAD_SOUNDS' : ('DOWNLOADING' + downloadProgress +'%')) | translate }}
```

I guess the downloadInProgess is available to the current scope

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do the following:

```
<button class="button button-full button-outline button-positive welcomeButton"
ng-click="downloadData()">
  <span translate="downloadProgress ? 'DOWNLOADING' : 'DOWNLOAD_SOUNDS'"
  translate-values="{progress: downloadProgress}"></span>
  <ion-spinner class="spinner-positive welcomePageDownloadProgressSpinner"
  ng-if="downloadProgress >=0" icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>
</button>
```

- Using the `translate` tag will prevent that the translation keys gets rendered on the button while loading your translation keys.
- Since you are translating you should use keys with values and use the `translation-values` tag for filling them. Since there are several languages that would not order the words in the same way.
  Your key could look something like `"DOWNLOADING": "Downloading: {{progress}}%",`

Comment: I updated angular-translate but rendered HTML result is now corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

On controller:

```
$scope.buttonText= 'DOWNLOAD_SOUNDS';
```

HTML

```
<button ng-click="downloadData()"
       class="button button-full button-outline button-positive welcomeButton">
          {{ buttonText | translate }}
</button>
```

In your function change the value in scope

```
$scope.buttonText= 'DOWNLOADING' + somevalueofpercent + '%';
```

It will automatically change the text of button and on completing change the text something else